# Adding an icon beside a button in CSS

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to do something as "trivial" as this in CSS with bootstrap but I am having no luck. Can anyone help me out with how to add an icon with a background right beside my form button?

[image]

```
<form>
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">COOL BUTTON
     </button>
</form>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ekaU2/

Thanks!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it lacks minimal effort from OP to solve the problem and is a "do it for me" question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use any image or icon for that, but if you use [bootstrap icons](http://getbootstrap.com/components/) for example, you can do it like that:

```
<form>
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
         COOL BUTTON
         <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
     </button>
</form>
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ekaU2/3/)</kbd>

Comment: I have a seperate icon that I will use but I get the idea. But what I am having trouble with is setting the background and width of the icon. http://jsfiddle.net/ekaU2/5/

Comment: You have the span tag out of the button tag. Fixed here: http://jsfiddle.net/acor/5B66P/

Comment: Ah, I think I am understanding this now. I tried having the span inside but for some reason I didn't think of adding padding and making some adjustments to make it look like a box inside the button. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Have you unticked my answer for any reason?

Comment: whoops! don't know how it happened. Sorry!

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `:after` pseudo class.

```
.btn:after {
    content: " ";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    right: -60px;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    background: #ddd url(path/to/img) no-repeat center center
}
```

This method requires no alteration of the HTML.

Here's a demo: [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ekaU2/4/)